# one decimal for string format

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have below digits. I want to show one digit after to decimal. How to format it?

```
2.85
2
1.99
```

I was using ("{0:0.0}". But data showing like

```
2.9 //It should be 2.8
2.0 //It should be 2
2.0 //It should be 1.9
```

Comment: (strict rounding-down is pretty unusual)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `"{0:0.#}"` as the format string. However, that will only fix the `.0`. To fix the  rounding to *always round down*, you might want to use:

```
string s = (Math.Floor(value * 10) / 10).ToString("0.#");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Decimal[] decimals = { new Decimal(2.85), new Decimal(2), new Decimal(1.99) };

foreach (var x in decimals)
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.#}", Decimal.Truncate(x * 10) / 10));
}

// output
2.8
2
1.9
```